# window can't have focus on header click extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, header, window

What's the method name for a window header click? The problem is that the window doesn't have focus when the header is clicked, I've spent my time to check but no result so can anyone help me, thanks.

Comment: Please provide the current code you are using, otherwise people will not be able to answer. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I added a link to a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1le7)

You could add an after render to your window object and manually add an on click event to the header of the window

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(component, eOpts) {
    document.getElementById(component.header.id).onclick = function myFunction() {
        console.log("You clicked the window header");
    };
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Not really a good practise, why if you're using extjs you should use document.getElementById? and why you use html element listeners? It works but not in the best way

Answer (score 0):

You should't use document references if you're using extJS, [here is a simple way](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ltm) to add a click listener to the header on element creation.

You can simply add a listener to it like all the others components, just doing this:

```
header:{
   listeners:{
       click:function( header , e , eOpts){
           console.log("You clicked the window header");
       }
   }
}
```

ps. [I forked michwalk solution to show my example in the same way](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ltm)

Comment: Ah you're right! I'm using Architect and didn't see the the header for a window could be specified as an object so I was looking for a work around. Good to know!